# What could be the problem of a queue that does not have a jndi-name in jboss.xml?

Tags: jboss, message-queue

I'm trying to migrate from jboss 4 to jboss 6 with an application i have running on jboss 4.
But when i try to run the application i get the following exception:

```
DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:binding=message-driven-bean,jndiName=local/ProjectMessage@15042526,plugin=invoker,service=EJB" is in error due to the following reason(s): org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: The message-destination 'PhysicalQueue' has no jndi-name in jboss.xml
```

This is a part of the jboss.xml file:

```
<message-driven>
         <ejb-name>ProjectMessage</ejb-name>
         <destination-jndi-name>queue/PhysicalQueue</destination-jndi-name>
      </message-driven>
```

I have created the queue in the jmx-console.

I have tried to search for a solution for this problem, but i can't seem to find any.

Does anybody have a clue/suggestion of what could be wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The MDB error occurs because the queue does not exist when the MDB deploys. Once you create the queue in JMXConsole, it's too late  (unless you're really fast...:) ) and the queue configuration is not retained after AS restart.

You need to define your queue in **deploy/hornetq/hornetq-jms.xml**.

Something like this:

```
   <queue name="PhysicalQueue">
      <entry name="/queue/PhysicalQueue"/>
   </queue>
```